# Find the maximum area of a rectangle that can be drawn inside a circle's quarter

Tags: calculus, geometry, optimization

How can I find the maximum area of the rectangle here? Given that the circle's radius is 6.
[image]

Any hint please?

Comment: Maybe you can parametrise the rectangle? Maybe set the width of the rectangle to be $x$ and then calculate its area ...

Comment: I tried, but I couldn't find any useful relationship between the width and the height.

Comment: Just make a big drawing, draw some auxiliary lines and see what you can come up with.

Comment: I suspect the square with a vertex at the origin and opposite vertex at $(3\sqrt{2},3\sqrt{2}$)$ with area $18$ may be bigger

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Choosing one vertex to be $(r \cos\theta, r\sin\theta)$ then another is $(r (\cos\theta- \sin\theta),0)$, a third is $(0,r (\cos\theta- \sin\theta))$ and the fourth is $(r \sin\theta, r\cos\theta)$

The area is then $2r^2 \sin\theta(\cos\theta- \sin\theta) = \sqrt{8}r^2 \sin(\theta) \sin\left(\frac\pi4-\theta\right) $ which is maximised when $\theta= \frac\pi8$ with the maximum area being $r^2(\sqrt{2}-1)$

*Added to illustrate comment:*  If the arrangement is not symmetric, you will not get two vertices on the arc and two on the axes.  Instead you will get coomething like this

[image]

Comment: Didn't get it how you assigned the coordinates of each vertex, can you explain please?

Comment: @Just_Cause - Are you happy with the  $(r \cos\theta, r\sin\theta)$ as a point on the circle?  That lies on the line $y=x + r(\cos \theta - \sin \theta)$ and so the next vertex is where that line intersects $y=0$.  The other two vertices are reflections in the line $y=x$

Comment: Sure, but how did you assume that the small triangle near the x axis is isosceles? (45 45 90)? Doesn't this lead to the fact that the bigger triangle is isosceles too?

Comment: @Just_Cause If you do not have symmetry then either the vertices are not on the arc and axes or the quadrilateral is not a rectangle.  So the triangle is isosceles

Comment: Still don't get what has symmetry got to do here, do you mean the symmetry line of the triangle, you used it to divide the bigger triangle into two halves which would bisect the 90 angle?

Comment: @Just_Cause Try to draw a rectangle with two vertices on the arc and two on the axes which is not symmetric about the line $y=x$: you will find it impossible instead getting something like my illustration

Answer (score 0):

I would compute the coordinates of the given points:
$$A(x_A,0),B(x_B,\sqrt{6^2-x_B^2}),C(x_C,\sqrt{6^2-x_C^2}),D(0,y_B)$$ Now it must be
$$\vec{AB}=[x_B-x_A,\sqrt{6^2-x_B^2}]$$ and $$\vec{AD}=[-x_A,y_D]$$ and it must be
$$\vec{AB}\cdot \vec{AD}=0$$
Can you proceed?

Comment: Appreciated, but I'm not really required to solve it using vectors.

Answer (score 0):

Let $ABCD$ be our rectangle, where $A$ be placed on the perpendicular radius and $D$ be placed on the horizontal radius.

Also, let $OE$ be a radius of the circle such that $OE\perp AD$, $OE\cap BC=\{F\}$, $OE\cap AD=\{G\}$ and let $HE$ be a diameter of the circle.

Now, since $G$ is a midpoint of $BC$, we obtain that $G$ is a midpoint of $AD$.

Thus, $OG=AG=DG$ and let $OG=x$, $DC=y$.

Now, since $\measuredangle ECH=90^{\circ},$ we obtain:
$$CE^2=EG\cdot GH$$ or
$$x^2=(6-x-y)(6+x+y)$$ or
$$(x+y)^2=36-x^2$$ or
$$y=\sqrt{36-x^2}-x.$$
Id est, $$S_{ABCD}=2x\left(\sqrt{36-x^2}-x\right).$$
Can you end it now?

Comment: Sure, but how did you get to $CE^2=EG\cdot GH$ ?

Comment: Because the triangle CGH is a right-angled triangle and CE is an altitude of the triangle.

Comment: Oh, i got it. One last thing that confuses me, is it permissible to assume that the radius is perpendicular on AD without an additional information from the question that denotes that?  i.e OE bisects AD?  As far as i know,  i can't put any assumptions unless the question states a key info on some theorem

Comment: @Just_Cause If $OE\perp AD$ then $OE\perp BC$, which gives $BF=FC$ and from here $AG=GD.$